# Running a command with access to "System Events.app" granted

Tags: applescript, security, homebrew, iterm

I am updating applications installed via Homebrew from command line. iTerm2 requires access to "System Events.app" to be correctly updated, which ends up in a process that is not fully automated and requires clicking on the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

Is it possible to avoid it, i.e. grant access to that kind of changes for a given command?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the AppleScript code it's impossible to say if there is another way around it; however, the fact that your current code has triggered that dialog box... you have no choice but to deal with it.